# Use the default System Screen Lock on minSDK19

Tags: android, lockscreen

is there any alternativ to  `createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent`, to invoke the default screen-lock View?

---

```
    KeyguardManager kgm = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(this.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = kgm.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent("title", "description");
    if(intent != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT);
    }
```

---

I have to use minSDK version 19.